# Before vs. earlier

Tags: grammaticality

I heard someone saying ...

> Have you done this work earlier?

They wanted to ask whether the listener had prior experience in doing that particular work.

I have always asked such questions differently, like ...

> Have you done this before?
> Have you had experience in this work in the past?

Are the above sentences correct?

Comment: What's "Have done this before?" supposed to mean? Lacks subject?

Comment: "Have you had experience in work in the past?" sounds like you're asking if they've ever done any kind of work, rather than that work in particular. You'd have to say "in this work"/"in that work".

Answer (score 0):

- Do you have **prior** work experience.  I would not use before or earlier.

However, one can use: Have you done this work **before**? [before now or today] before means: *at another point in the past*.

It is a preposition. *before* will often imply: before this or before that or before some  point but it is often just stuck on the end of a spoken utterance.

earlier refers to an earlier time period.

- Did you do this task earlier [in the day or this month or this year].
  Answer: Yes, I did the task at 6 o'clock.
- Have you done this work *earlier in your career*?
  Answer: Yes, I did this work for three years but don't do it now.

early, earlier/later. These are adjectives.

before/afterwards/after this. *before* is a conjunction or preposition. In the sentences above, before is a preposition.